# Problems defining my own Android theme

Tags: android, xml, themes

Is there anything wrong with this XML? I don't get any compile time errors, but anytime I try to edit it, Eclipse gives me a nullpointerexception. Why?

**/res/values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
      <!-- Base application theme is the default theme. -->
      <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">
      </style>

      <!-- Variation on our application theme that has a translucent
     background. -->
      <style name="Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/translucent_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
      </style>

      <!-- Variation on our application theme that has a transparent
    background; this example completely removes the background,
    allowing the activity to decide how to composite. -->
      <style name="Theme.Transparent">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/transparent_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
      </style>
      <style name="TextAppearance.Theme.PlainText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Theme">
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
      </style>

    </resources>
```

Comment: Often, when Eclipse pops up a message, you can just drag it out of the way instead of closing it and letting it happen again. Alternatively, try editing the XML file in Eclipse with a non-Android editor or with the plain text editor.

Comment: Good solution, that is what I have done. You should post your comment as an answer so I can check it off :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this a couple times as well. I did a Project->Clean and then restarted eclipse. When it came back up the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing pops out at me right away, just make sure you have `transparent_background` and `translucent_background` in your `res/drawable` folder.